# How to check if variable is an Enum or a Case?

Tags: php, enums, php-8.1

There is a lot of type checking functions in PHP (`is_string`, `is_resource` etc) but there is no function to check if variable is an Enum or a Case. How to check it properly?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.enum-exists.php

Answer (score 2):

You can check that it implements the [UnitEnum](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.unitenum.php) interface.

```
if ($variable instanceof UnitEnum) echo "it's an enum.";
```

According to the PHP manual, this interface exists specifically for type checking.

Comment: This is a duplicate question and your advice is found on the dupe target.